# how to join two table with optimized query

Tags: sql, teradata

I have two table and I have to do a join  to have this result, I used this query but it takes a lot of time to run, who can help me to have this result with a optimized query

```
SELECT  top 10  subs_id, REFILL_VALUE, refill_type, Subscription_type, Category
FROM   P_EDW_BO_UNIVERSE.VOUCHER_BY_SUBSCRIBER_DETAIL a , P_EDW_BO_UNIVERSE.offer b
where a.offering_id=b.Offer_ID and DATE_INSERTED = '2017/06/07' 

table A
--------
id |name | adresse | number |
1    kh      kouba    4586
2    hi      bouz     7854

table B
-----------
id  | offer
1     post
2     pre
3     pai
```

i want have this result 
result

```
id | name | adresse | number | offer
1     kh    kouba     4586      post
2     hi    bouz      7854      pre
```

Comment: I'm confused by your current query because you select columns which do not appear in the actual table definitions.

Comment: Dont use old joins they look nasty, do you have any indexes on your joins?

Comment: How many rows are in both tables and your result? What's the DDL (at least PIs)? What exactly is *a lot of time*? Can you show Explain?

Answer (score 0):

```
  Select id,name,adresse,number,offer
  from A
  join B
  on A.id=B.id
```

I used `A` and `B` as table names , change them depending on your table name.
the `id` is a primary key on one table and a foreign key on the other

Comment: @khedidjatihar: How can this improve performance? It's exactly the same as the original Select, just using explicit vs. implicit join syntax.